# Error by importing Gradle Project into Eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

i newby in Gradle Projects.

I receive now a project and i need to import then to Eclipse.

Gradle is installed and work fine.

When i go to Eclipse and  try to import a grandle project  using build model i got this error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\application\xpto\git-repo\xpto\xpto\Workspace\build.gradle' line: 42
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Workspace'.

  > C:\Users\myid\Downloads\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32\eclipse.....\Distribution\gradle-settings\config.groovy (folder cannot b found)
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Workspace'.
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)

One important point.

1 - "Workspace" is the name from the Folder who i have my projects.

I would like to know why during importing he is considering my eclipse Folder, where i can change it.
here a short part of the build.gradle file.

```
ext {
xpto_buildBaseDir     = "./../../"
xpto_buildTempDir     = "$xpto_buildBaseDir/_temp"
xpto_buildFileDir     = "$xpto_buildBaseDir/Build_Process/Distribution"
xpto_buildSettingsDir = "$xpto_buildFileDir/gradle-settings" 
xpto_buildDir         = "$xpto_buildTempDir/building directory"
xpto_earDir           = "$xpto_buildDir/ears"
xpto_appConfDir       = "$xpto_buildBaseDir/Application_Configuration"
```

}

and the row 42 we have.

```
    ext.config = new ConfigSlurper(environment).parse(new File("$buildSettingsDir/config.groovy").toURL())
```

I'm using Gradle 1.5

Anyone can help me in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `new File("$buildSettingsDir/config.groovy")`, it should be `file("$buildSettingsDir/config.groovy")`. As a general rule, always use `file(...)` instead of `new File(...)` in build scripts, as otherwise relative paths won't be resolved correctly.